# Running Java CORBA Client on Unix

Tags: java, corba

I'm trying to run a Java application I wrote to subscribe to a CORBA event service.  It runs OK on my Windows machine, but as soon as I deploy it to the UNIX server, it gives me an org.omg.CORBA.NO_IMPLEMENT exception.  Any ideas as to why this might be happening?  I'm using JacORB on my Windows machine and passing VM arguments to initialize the client ORB, but I'm not sure how to do that on UNIX and if it's even necessary.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How are you running the Corba client on Unix? Are you running it from the command line or in a Java EE container?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JRE comes with a full Corba implementation and you need to tell it to ignore those and use JacOrb instead.

On Unix:

```
-Xbootclasspath:${JACORB_HOME}/lib/jacorb.jar:${JAVA_HOME}/jre/lib/rt.jar:${CLASSPATH} 
-Dorg.omg.CORBA.ORBClass=org.jacorb.orb.ORB
-Dorg.omg.CORBA.ORBSingletonClass=org.jacorb.orb.ORBSingleton
```

Look up the [docs for JacORB](http://www.jacorb.org/documentation.html) 
It is very well explained. You need to have the jars files installed and you need to point to either the ior or the nameservice passed into your JVM.

If your question is how to do this in a shell then please comment or rephrase the question.

Comment: I ended up moving to a tangent linux machine and installed a newer version of the JDK and JacORB, which fixed the issues I was running into.  Thanks everyone for the input.

Answer (score 0):

The Javadoc for [org.omg.CORBA.NO_IMPLEMENTIMPLEMENT](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/omg/CORBA/NO_IMPLEMENT.html):

> This exception indicates that even though the operation that was invoked exists (it has an IDL definition), no implementation for that operation exists. NO_IMPLEMENT can, for example, be raised by an ORB if a client asks for an object's type definition from the interface repository, but no interface repository is provided by the ORB.
>
> It contains a **minor code, which gives more detailed information** about what caused the exception, and a completion status. It may also **contain a string describing the exception**

So I guess you need to look at what the Exception exactly says. My bet is that you need to add those java arguments to initialize the ORB client.

Answer (score 0):

If the versions differ it could be that you haven't noticed the change of package names in JacORB 1.3.21 tha names have changed from jacorb to **org**.jacorb

```
org.omg.CORBA.ORBClass=jacorb.orb.ORB
org.omg.CORBA.ORBSingletonClass=jacorb.orb.ORBSingleton
```

to this:

```
org.omg.CORBA.ORBClass=org.jacorb.orb.ORB
org.omg.CORBA.ORBSingletonClass=org.jacorb.orb.ORBSingleton
```

If this isn't the cause, please post exact verions